# MVC Entity Framework with Raw SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have the following two methods:

```
public IEnumerable<MyModel> GetDetails()
{

        var Results1 = GetFromSql(typeof(MyModel),
          "SELECT t1.field1,t2.field2,t3.field3,t4.field4 " +
          "FROM table1 t1 " +
          "INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id " +
          "INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id=t3.id " +
          "INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t1.id=t4.id ");

        var Results2 = (from t1 in context.repository.Get()
                join t2 in context.repository.Get() on t1.id equals t2.id
                join t3 in context.repository.Get() on t1.id equals t3.id
                join t4 in context.repository.Get() on t1.id equals t4.id

        select new MyModel()
        {
             field1 = t1.field1,
             field2 = t2.field2,
             field3 = t3.field3,
             field4 = t4.field4}).ToList();
        });

        return Results2;

}

private dynamic GetFromSql(System.Type returnType, string strSql)
{
    var items = _context.Database.SqlQuery(returnType, strSql);
    return items;
}
```

Currently, Result2 is returned as a System.Collections.Generic.List and Result1 is being returned as a dynamic (System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbRawSqlQuery).

How can I get Results1 to return a List exactly the same as Results2?

I have tried using typeof(List) in place of typeof(MyModel), but this didn't work.

(I know it would seem that I should just use Results2, but I have my reasons.)

Comment: `How can I get Results1 to return a List exactly the same as Results2?` <= What returns now when you run `Result1`? Do you get an Exception or  build error? Is the resulting structure different from `Result2`? Is the data different from `Result2`? Why do you want to work with Raw Sql over a Lambda? You stated you have reasons but what are they? What occurs in generating `Result2` that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: I am avoiding Result2 because 1) the actual SQL statement for Result1 involves using STUFF to do a Group Concat, 2) there are actually 7 tables involves and 12 non-concat fields, 3) I haven't found anything online that sufficiently explains how to do a Group Concat with Lambda that includes other fields in the result set.  I don't get any errors, just the results in a different way.

Comment: `I don't get any errors, just the results in a different way.` <= I am not sure what that means. So the data that is returned contains or does not contain the expected records? If so I do not see how we can possibly answer your question to generate the correct query given the lack of detail. If that is not what you meant please clarify your question, *what exactly* is the expected result and the current actual result.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of clarity.  I guess I need to know how to convert a System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DBRawSqlQuery as a List?  Or would I just need to loop through the result of the query and add elements to the list individually?

Comment: Why doesn't `var results = _context.Database.SqlQuery<MyModel>(strSql);` work?

Comment: I inherited this project, and I can't seem to find a way to directly execute that statement...still looking...

Comment: I have given up on this, and going back to trying to find a way to use STUFF with LINQ.  What a nightmare.