# Group Concatenation with Linq

Tags: linq

I have this:

```
var lstAssignmentDetails =  
     (from t1 in _unitOfWork.ReferralDetailsRepository.Get()
    .Where(m => (m.ChartStatusID == (int)Utility.ReferralChartStatus.NotStaffed 
         || m.ChartStatusID == (int)Utility.ReferralChartStatus.Partially_Staffed 
         || m.ChartStatusID == (int)Utility.ReferralChartStatus.Restaff) 
         && m.IsDeleted == false).OrderByDescending(x => x.ReferralDetailsId)  
    join t2 in _unitOfWork.ReferralRepository.Get() on t1.ReferralId equals t2.ReferralId
    join t3 in _unitOfWork.PatientRepository.Get() on t2.PatientId equals t3.PatientId
    join t4 in _unitOfWork.ClientRepository.Get() on t2.ClientId equals t4.ClientID
    join t5 in _unitOfWork.DisciplineRepository.Get() on t1.DesciplineID equals t5.DesciplineID
    join t6 in _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get() on t2.CreatedBy equals t6.UserID
    join t7 in _unitOfWork.PersonRepository.Get() on t6.PersonID equals t7.PersonID
    join rt in _unitOfWork.ReferralTherapistRepository.Get() on t2.ReferralId equals rt.ReferralId
    join t in _unitOfWork.TherapistRepository.Get() on rt.TherapistId equals t.TherapistId 
    join u in _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get() on t.UserId equals u.UserID
    join p in _unitOfWork.PersonRepository.Get() on u.PersonID equals p.PersonID

select new ReferralTempModel()
{
    ReferralId = t1.ReferralId,
    ClientName = t4.ClientName,
    PatientName = t3.LastName + "," + t3.FirstName,
    RefferalDate = t2.RefferalDate,
    DisciplineID = t1.DisciplineID,
    ReferralDetailsId = t1.ReferralDetailsId,
    PatientId = t2.PatientId,
    ClientID = t4.ClientID,
    DiscName = t5.DesciplineType,
    IsRejected = t1.IsRejected,
    CreatedBy = t7.LastName + "," + t7.FirstName,
    ChartstatusId = t1.ChartStatusID.Value
}).ToList();

return lstAssignmentDetails;
```

There are multiple ReferralTherapists for each referral.  I need all the ReferralTherapists for each referral to be concatenated into one field.  Essentially what I want to do is a GROUP_CONCAT using LINQ.

I know this is probably a duplicate, but none of the previous questions handles anything as complicated as this.  Trying to add GroupBy always seems to create an error no matter where I place it.

Comment: You have a therapist object `t`, therapist user object `u`, and therapist's person object `p`. Which ones would you like to concatenate?

Comment: The therapists' names are in the person table.  I would like the names to be concatenated.

Answer (score 1):

Start by *not* joining other referrals as `t2` when constructing your flat list, and adding therapist's name to the anonymous type:

```
var flatListAssignmentDetails =  
     (from t1 in _unitOfWork.ReferralDetailsRepository.Get()
    .Where(m => (m.ChartStatusID == (int)Utility.ReferralChartStatus.NotStaffed 
         || m.ChartStatusID == (int)Utility.ReferralChartStatus.Partially_Staffed 
         || m.ChartStatusID == (int)Utility.ReferralChartStatus.Restaff) 
         && !m.IsDeleted)
    join t2 in _unitOfWork.ReferralRepository.Get() on t1.ReferralId equals t2.ReferralId
    join t3 in _unitOfWork.PatientRepository.Get() on t2.PatientId equals t3.PatientId
    join t4 in _unitOfWork.ClientRepository.Get() on t2.ClientId equals t4.ClientID
    join t5 in _unitOfWork.DisciplineRepository.Get() on t1.DesciplineID equals t5.DesciplineID
    join t6 in _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get() on t2.CreatedBy equals t6.UserID
    join t7 in _unitOfWork.PersonRepository.Get() on t6.PersonID equals t7.PersonID
select new {
    t1.ReferralId,
    t4.ClientName,
    PatientName = t3.LastName + "," + t3.FirstName,
    t2.RefferalDate,
    t1.DisciplineID,
    t1.ReferralDetailsId,
    t2.PatientId,
    t4.ClientID,
    DiscName = t5.DesciplineType,
    t1.IsRejected,
    CreatedBy = t7.LastName + "," + t7.FirstName,
    ChartstatusId = t1.ChartStatusID.Value,
    TherapistName = p.LastName + "," + p.FirstName
}).ToList();
```

Now you can group your list, and concatenate therapist names:

```
var listAssignmentDetails = flatListAssignmentDetails
    .GroupBy(r => r.ReferralId)
    .Select(g => new ReferralTempModel {
        ReferralId = g.First().ReferralId,
        ClientName = g.First().ClientName,
        PatientName = g.First().PatientName,
        RefferalDate = g.First().RefferalDate,
        DisciplineID = g.First().DisciplineID,
        ReferralDetailsId = g.First().ReferralDetailsId,
        PatientId = g.First().PatientId,
        ClientID = g.First().ClientID,
        DiscName = g.First().DiscName,
        IsRejected = g.First()..IsRejected,
        CreatedBy = g.First().CreatedBy,
        ChartstatusId = g.First().ChartStatusID,
        TherapistNames = string.Join(", ", g.Select(r => r.TherapistName))
    }).ToList();
```

One thing to note here is that all fields that are tied to all referrals in the group are obtained through `g.First()` construct. The field with "group concatenation" is produced using `string.Join` method on a projection of `TherapistName` from the group.

Comment: Not sure I understand why t2 is being taken out.  t2 is the main referral table, and most of the joins fail when this is taken out.

Comment: When I put t2 back, it worked just fine, except that I think it may be better to join on referraldetailsid.  Checking on this.

Comment: @RichardMartin I misunderstood your query - I thought you were self-joining `ReferralRepository` to itself, not realizing that `t1` is actually `ReferralDetailsRepository`. This is now fixed.

Comment: Now my problem is that the ReferralTherapistRepository needs to be LEFT JOIN'ed...and from what I have been reading so far, this is going to be a doozy!

Comment: @RichardMartin Then do a join manually. Drop the last three joins, replace `TherapistName` with `TherapistId`, get your groups, extract therapist IDs from all groups, retrieve therapists by IDs (what was in the three joins would go into the therapist query), and then go through your groups, and construct a list of therapist names. That sounds complicated, but it might be easier than doing an outer join three levels deep.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance.  I am an old-school SQL guy and find this Lambda Linq stuff kinda useless.  Unfortunately, I inherited this project that is chock-full of it.  I tried doing the above with a good old-fashioned SQL statement, but couldn't seem to figure out how to convert the result to a List.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539725/mvc-entity-framework-with-raw-sql?noredirect=1#comment86088116_49539725